# Find permutation of N numbers which gives the sum of X

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, programming

Assume

```
  n = 3  //A,B,C
  x = 6
```

How to find all permutaions of three numbers which makes to the total of 6.
For example how to calculate how many permutations we can find.

```
A   B   C
----------
0   0   6
0   6   0
6   0   0

0   1   5
1   0   5
0   5   1
1   5   0
5   0   1
5   1   0

0   2   4
1   1   4
2   0   4
0   4   2
2   4   0
1   4   1
4   1   1
4   0   2
4   2   0

3   0   3
3   3   0
0   3   3

3   2   1
3   1   2
1   3   2
2   3   1
1   2   3
2   1   3

2   2   2
```

What is the formula to count the purmutations for given x and n, to get results like above?
Is there any programatical way to do this

Comment: Please provide reason why its voted down, so the question can be improved, Please read stack exchage guidelines, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: Have a look at [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The answer is $\binom82=28$ or more generally $\binom{x+n-1}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

First, find how many different groups of numbers sum to $6$, and write them as an unordered set.
$\left \{ 1,2,3 \right \},\left \{6,0,0 \right \},\left \{5,1,0 \right \},\left \{2,4,0 \right \}$ 
Now find how many ways you can "shuffle" or arrange the numbers in each of these sets.
Each set has $3$ elements, that means there are $3!$ ways to arrange each set. There are $4$ sets, so; $3!\times4=28$